# trying to convert modenizr code to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand what this modenizr code is doing so I can simplify it and convert it to a jquery call for my click event.

Here is the current modenizr code:

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {

var transformProp = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
    transitionProp = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
    transitionEnd = (function() {
        var props = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
            'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition'       : 'transitionend'
        };
        return props.hasOwnProperty(transitionProp) ? props[transitionProp] : false;
    })(),

    hasTT = transitionEnd && transitionProp && transitionProp;

var log = function(obj)
{
    if (typeof window.console === 'object' && typeof window.console.log === 'function') {
        window.console.log(obj);
    }
};

window.App = (function()
{

    var _init = false, app = { };

    app.init = function()
    {
        if (_init) {
            return;
        }
        _init = true;

        app.win    = $(window);
        app.docEl  = $(document.documentElement);
        app.bodyEl = $(document.body);

        app.docEl.addClass('js-ready js-' + (hasTT ? 'advanced' : 'basic'));

        var menuLinkEl = $('#menu-link'),
            menuEl = $('#menu'),
            wrapEl = $('#wrap');

        var closeMenu =function()
        {
            if (hasTT) {
                menuEl.one(transitionEnd, function(e) {
                    app.docEl.removeClass('js-offcanvas');
                });
            } else {
                app.docEl.removeClass('js-offcanvas');
            }
            app.docEl.removeClass('js-menu');
        };

        var openMenu = function()
        {
            app.docEl.addClass('js-offcanvas js-menu');
        };

        menuLinkEl.on('click', function(e)
        {
            if (app.docEl.hasClass('js-menu')) {
                closeMenu();
            } else {
                openMenu();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });



    };

    return app;

})();


})(window, window.document);
```

I've made an attempt to convert everything with the exception of the transform (hasTT) Will my conversion work and how do I transform the hasTT call?

My Attempt:

```
var appWin    = $(window);
var appDocEl  = $(document.documentElement);

appDocEl.addClass('js-ready js-' + (hasTT ? 'advanced' : 'basic'));

var menuLinkEl = $('#menu-link'),
    menuEl = $('#menu'),
    wrapEl = $('#wrap');

var closeMenu =function() 
{
    /* how do I determine hasTT ? */
    if (hasTT) {
        menuEl.one(transitionEnd, function(e) {
            appDocEl.removeClass('js-offcanvas');
        });
    } else {
        appDocEl.removeClass('js-offcanvas');
    }
    appDocEl.removeClass('js-menu');
};

var openMenu = function(){
    appDocEl.addClass('js-offcanvas js-menu');
};

menuLinkEl.on('click', function(e){
    if (appDocEl.hasClass('js-menu')) {
        closeMenu();
    } 
    else {
        openMenu();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I currently load it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    loadMain();
});

function loadMain() {

        Modernizr.load([
            {
             load: [
                    'http://localhost/js/main.js'
                ],
                complete: function()
                {
                    window.App.init();
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm having issues with modenizr on older mobile browsers like android 2.3.  It seems to be caching this init call and only happening initially when the page loads

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to jQuery ? jQuery is slower than pure javascript.

Comment: You can dynamically load the script with `$.getScript`

Comment: pure javascript would work, I'm just trying to understand it and simplify it.

Comment: There's a reason it's written the way it is, it's an open source project being used by millions of sites, and if there where issues or better way to write it, it surely would have been done.

Comment: @adeneo What would be a good work around for older broswers? Do I do as Jaswant suggested $.getScript on every page?

Comment: You may have a transcription error in your modernizr code above.  hasTT = transitionEnd && transformProp && transitionProp; maybe should not be hasTT = transitionEnd && transitionProp && transitionProp;  - - not that this answers your question but maybe why you're having an issue.

Comment: @J E Carter II Good catch. didn't solve my issue but a good find!

Comment: if you don't understand it...how can you simplify it? Has been well tested across thousands of sites and likely every device and browser imagineable