# calling getscript and modenizr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the feedback of my earlier thread: [trying to convert modenizr code to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079129/trying-to-convert-modenizr-code-to-jquery) it was suggested that I use $.getScript to load my javascript dynamically. How do I make the  window.App.init(); call from $.getScript?

The original modenizr call:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        loadMain();
});

function loadMain() {

    Modernizr.load([
    {
            load: [
                    'http://localhost/js/main.js'
                  ],
                complete: function()
                {
                       window.App.init();
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

Using $.getScript doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
function loadMain() {

    $.getScript('http://localhost/js/main.js', function () {
        window.App.init();
    });
}
```

Comment: It won't matter, using $.getScript won't make it into jQuery or make it work for old browsers.

Comment: it ends up being a click event for a sliding menu so should I just simplify it for older browsers?

Comment: Modernizr needs to run immediately, not after DOM ready or asynch request. Might be better that you explain problem you are trying to solve, rather than present what doesn't seem like a good solution

Comment: @charlietfl I see this on older android browsers (2.3.X) Try opening: http://nightskyadmin.com/demo-bs3/template/dashboard.html and after loading a second page and you go back the menu no longer works.